# Getting keys from a dictionary: keys() vs 'keys for keys in dict.keys()'

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to figure out best coding practices as I'm getting started with python. I wrote a csv to dataframe reader with pandas. It uses the format:

```
dataframe = read_csv(csv_input, usecols=column_names, dtype=test_dictionary)
```

We're using a dictionary to determine the columns we want to import along with their associated data types. For example:

```
test_dictionary = {'column1': int, 'column2': float, 'column3': string}
```

Now to assign the second argument, usecols, we can take the keys from a dictionary in order to get just the names of the columns (column1, column2, column3). I used the keys method:

```
column_names = test_dictionary.keys()
```

Someone checking my code changed it to this instead:

```
column_names = [keys for keys in test_dictionary.keys()]
```

Could someone explain to me why one would choose one method over the other for assigning the keys in a dictionary to a variable?

Comment: All I can see is an explicit array declaration versus the method you used.

Comment: There's no reason to do that. If `column_names` absolutely has to be a list rather than a `dict_keys` object, just use `list(test_dictionary.keys())`.

Comment: `[keys for keys in test_dictionary.keys()]` is a very silly way of writing `list(test_dictionary.keys())` which is a slightly silly way of writing `list(test_dictionary)`

Comment: Although, an important quesiton is, are you on Python 2 or 3, because `dict.keys` acts very differently

Comment: @Greg other than the type of `dict_keys` object, I believe the answer was useful. It doesn't support indexing, slicing etc. This is probably the reason to convert it to a list.

Comment: @Greg yeah, I would just edit to address the comments I was leaving. Another important distinction, `list(some_dict().keys())` (which should really just be `list(some_dict)` is an O(N) operation, wheres `some_dict.keys()` is O(1).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am using Python 3

Comment: @ayhan well, a `dict_keys` is essentially  a set-like-view on the underlying `dict`. It is quite different than a list of keys, and has several advantages.

Comment: From python documentation: "Calling d.keys() will return a dictionary view object. It supports operations like membership test and iteration, but its contents are not independent of the original dictionary – it is only a view."

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python 3, `keys()` does not return a list, but rather [a "view" of the keys in the dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict-views).

```
>>> d = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> keys = d.keys()
>>> keys
dict_keys(['x', 'y', 'z'])
```

This view differs from lists in two major ways:

1. You cannot modify it:

   ```
   >>> keys.append('k')
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute 'append'
   ```
2. If the dictionary changes, the view reflects those changes:

   ```
   >>> del d['z']
   >>> keys
   dict_keys(['x', 'y'])
   ```

You might want to turn this view into a list if you need to modify it or if you want it to be independent from the original dictionary.

Other than lists, other standard containers that are suitable for these purposes are sets (read-write) and tuple or frozensets (read-only).

One thing worth mentioning is that this code:

```
column_names = [keys for keys in test_dictionary.keys()]
```

Can be rewritten in a more compact and fast way like this (thanks [Cleb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1534017/cleb) for pointing it out!):

```
column_names = list(test_dictionary)
```

Another thing to note is that iterating over a list might be slightly faster than iterating over the view. That's because list have a better memory representation. (However, this is a very generic statement: factors like the number of items in the dictionary, the time required to create the list, and the Python version can have great effect on the overall performance.)

Comment: Or just `list(test_dictionary)`